# My system screen goes black and displays Term Signal Killed?

Tags: 10.04

My computer will often just die randomly while I am using it. The screen goes black and sometimes displays the words TERM signal killed along with other things and sometimes it displays nothing. The writing stays on the screen momentarily before it disappears to just black. I then have to hold in the power button to turn it off and then re boot.

Here are the specs... help!

- Ubuntu 10.04(lucid)
- Kernel Linux 2.6.32-23-generic
- GNOME 2.30.2
- memory  495.7 MiB
- processor Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4CPU 1.80GHz

Comment: Check /var/log/messages it is likely to have more details on the unexpected shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

If it locks up randomly and not associated with a particular process (program you are running) then two thoughts come to mind.  You could have a bit of flaky memory that doesn't always get spotted right away.  The easy way to find out is to run the memory test from the boot cd - I'd let it churn overnight.

The other issue is that it might be heat related.  Any chance your processor fan has stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the computer is hibernating, are you actually actively using the computer when this happens or just reading something and not moving the mouse? System->Preferences->Power Management will allow you to disable hibernate if this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

i think the problem is in your computer screen (i mean the hardware, not software). Be sure to check it up to technician. Btw did you got the same problem when use other OS like windows or something? If yes, then i assure you that's the hardware problem..

Comment: -1 there is no indication that this is an hw problem, please do not answer with random guesses

Comment: i dont use any other OS.